# Programatically setting images widths based on container width

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6, logic

I have a series of images i'd liike to output per row. I ned these image to take up the ful width of each row in question. The only way I can think to to do this is by calculating the combined widths of the images vs container width. Then use the pecenateg difference to reduce the image widths.

I have this working nearly 100% as expected, but the images do not quite fill the space in some cases. There must be a flaw in my logic as this should always fit the space based on the calculations.

As you can see from the example below, the images do not quite line up in the righthand side. I think the flaw in my logic is on this line `return imageWidths + (60 * imgs.length);`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rev3tsuf/5/

[image]

JS:

```
function processImageRows(className, containerWidth) {
  let imgWidths = getImageWidthCombines(className);

  // initiate image width setting if too large for container
  if (imgWidths > containerWidth) {
    let percent = Math.ceil((containerWidth / imgWidths) * 100);
    getImageWidthCombines(className, percent);
  }
}

function getImageWidthCombines(className, percent = false) {
  // loop through images for given row and return combined width
  let imgs = document.querySelectorAll(`#image-wrapper .${ className } img.set-img`);
  let imageWidths = 0;
  imgs.forEach(function(el, index) {
    if (percent) {
      // if percentage is set that means we now set the widths as opposed to return their value
      el.style.width = `${Math.floor(el.width * (percent / 100))}px`;
    } else {
      el.style.width = null;
      imageWidths += el.offsetWidth;
    }
  });

  // ??? needs 60 added otherwsie doesn't get right percentage.
  return imageWidths + (60 * imgs.length);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-1">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x473.png" />
    </div>
    ... more images
  </div>
  <div class="row row-2">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/473x473.png" />
    </div>
    ... more images
  </div>
  <div class="row row-3">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/578x473.png" class="set-img" />
    </div>
    ... more images
  </div>
</div>
```

I also have a window resize event that triggers the above process, but i've left that out of the example in order to keep it simple.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It's taken me two days to get this far, and half a day stuck on this one issue, now i'm completely stuck with nothing more to try.

Comment: It seems to be rather CSS isssue. Wouldn't flexbox/flexgrid work better for you?

Comment: So you always want to have the img filling the 100% width no matter if image is smaller basicly, without streching image?

Comment: @MaxiGui in this case the images will always be larger than the container. So it's a case of reducing them to fit.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov my css/flex-box skills aren't too bad. I'm not sure though how this could be achieved purely using flex-box given they are different column widths. If you know how i'd be greatly appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

To adjust your work just customize CSS class as below:

```
.row {
  margin-right: -4px;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
.row .col-auto:first-child{
  margin-left: 0!important;                   /* ADDED */
}
.row .col-auto:last-child{ 
  margin-right: 0 !important;                 /* ADDED */
}
.row .col-auto{
  margin-left: auto;                          /* ADDED */ 
  margin-right:auto;                          /* ADDED */
}
.col-auto {
  padding-right: 4px !important;              /* ADDED !important */
  padding-left: 4px !important;               /* ADDED !important */
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

### DEMO with JS CODE your code:

```js
function processImageRows(className, containerWidth) {
  let imgWidths = getImageWidthCombines(className);

  // initiate image width setting if too large for container
  if (imgWidths > containerWidth) {
    let percent = Math.ceil((containerWidth / imgWidths) * 100);
    getImageWidthCombines(className, percent);
  }
}

function getImageWidthCombines(className, percent = false) {
  // loop through images for given row and return combined width
  let imgs = document.querySelectorAll(`#image-wrapper .${ className } img.set-img`);
  let imageWidths = 0;
  imgs.forEach(function(el, index) {
    if (percent) {
      // if percentage is set that means we now set the widths as opposed to return their value
      el.style.width = `${Math.floor(el.width * (percent / 100))}px`;
    } else {
      el.style.width = null;
      imageWidths += el.offsetWidth;
    }
  });

  // ??? needs 60 added otherwsie doesn't get right percentage.
  return imageWidths + (60 * imgs.length);
}

// this is called after each image load
function checkLoadingProgress() {

  let containerWidth = document.getElementById('image-wrapper').clientWidth;
  let imgsTotal = 0;
  let imgsLoaded = 0;

  // loop through rows
  ['row-1', 'row-2', 'row-3'].forEach(function(el, index) {
    imgsTotal = document.querySelectorAll(`#image-wrapper .${el} img.set-img`).length;
    imgsLoaded = document.querySelectorAll(`#image-wrapper .${el} img.set-img.image-loaded`).length;

    // only process is all images have loaded for the given row
    if (imgsLoaded > 0 && imgsLoaded == imgsTotal) {
      processImageRows(el, containerWidth);
    }
  });

  // finally all images have loaded. Updated loading class on container
  let allImgsTotal = document.querySelectorAll(`#image-wrapper img.set-img`).length;
  let allImgsLoaded = document.querySelectorAll(`#image-wrapper img.set-img.image-loaded`).length;

  if (allImgsTotal == allImgsLoaded) {
    document.getElementById('image-wrapper').classList.add('image-loaded');
    document.getElementById('image-wrapper').classList.remove('image-loading');
  }
}

// bind onload event to images
let imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img.set-img');
imgs.forEach(function(el, index) {
  el.addEventListener('load', function() {
    this.classList.add('image-loaded');
    checkLoadingProgress();
  }, false);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}
.row {
  margin-right: -4px;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
.row .col-auto:first-child{
  margin-left: 0!important;                   /* ADDED */
}
.row .col-auto:last-child{ 
  margin-right: 0 !important;                 /* ADDED */
}
.row .col-auto{
  margin-left: auto;                          /* ADDED */ 
  margin-right:auto;                          /* ADDED */
}
.col-auto {
  padding-right: 4px !important;              /* ADDED !important */
  padding-left: 4px !important;               /* ADDED !important */
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image-wrapper.images-loading .col-auto {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.image-wrapper.images-loaded .col-auto img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
<div id="image-wrapper" class="images-loading">
    <div class="row row-1">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x473.png" class="set-img" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/578x473.png" class="set-img" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/578x473.png" class="set-img" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x473.png" class="set-img"  />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-2">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/473x473.png" class="set-img" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1042x473.png" class="set-img" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/473x473.png" class="set-img" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-3">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/578x473.png" class="set-img" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/474x473.png" class="set-img" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/578x473.png" class="set-img" />
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

---

---

---

### BEFORE EDIT:

From the point you know the container size or use flex box, no need to have js, you can simply use CSS by fixing a container as below:

```
.flexible-container{
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

And then set img with class `w-100` and the below CSS:

```
.flexible-container img{
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Images size will be respected and won't be stretch as the extra height will be hidden by container `overflow: hidden;`.

With class `col` so automatic width as you seems to have you are grid, pretty much either use grid directly or customize flex class as below:

```
.flex-15{
  flex:1 1 15% !important;
}
.flex-30{
  flex:1 1 30% !important;
}
```

### DEMO:

```css
.row-1, .row-2, .row-3{
  height: 20vh;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.flexible-container{
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.flexible-container img{
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 1px;
}
.flex-15{
  flex:1 1 15% !important;
}
.flex-30{
  flex:1 1 30% !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-1">
    <div class="col flexible-container">
      <img class="w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x473.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col flex-15 flexible-container">
      <img class="w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/578x473.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col flex-15 flexible-container">
      <img class="w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/578x473.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col flexible-container">
      <img class="w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x473.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-2">
      <div class="col flexible-container">
        <img class="w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/473x473.png" class="set-img" />
      </div>
      <div class="col flexible-container flex-30">
        <img class="w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1042x473.png" class="set-img" />
      </div>
      <div class="col flexible-container">
        <img class="w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/473x473.png" class="set-img" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-3">
      <div class="col flexible-container flex-15">
        <img class="w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/578x473.png" class="set-img" />
      </div>
      <div class="col flexible-container">
        <img class="w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/473x473.png" class="set-img" />
      </div>
      <div class="col flexible-container flex-15">
        <img class="w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/578x473.png" class="set-img" />
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is using bootstrap columns. The columns need to be auto, or no col class at all. The row should be the images scaled to fit the container width. As per my image screenshot. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: so actualy you have 1 col by row with 1 single image ? rules will still apply let me edit

Comment: the first row will have 4 images, second row has 3 images and the 4th row has 3 images. Some of different widths

Comment: @steve I fyou already know the size of the container you want to do, you can make it this way. by setting directly a `flex` to your col. here it is with bs col auto, I just create `flex` classes

Comment: Thanks but this requires knowing the width of the images before hand in order to set the column width with the right class. It also doesn't have variable height.

Comment: @steve Not really, the image take the container size. So you set your container structure, as I did and then images will always fit. As your question is: "_Programatically setting images widths based on container width_", so it means that you know container width or you know how want to fix your container... If you meant : "_Programatically setting container width based on images width_", that is something else. The `height` is based on the `row` height you will fix

Comment: @steve Please have a look to the update, I have made a 2nd snippet based on your code and just adjusted CSS. I guess, result is how you expected.

Comment: Thanks, the images in your example have a set height, they don't scale to the natural height. If you look at the image i added in my question, you will see it doesn't set row height, that happens naturally. It also doesn't set column width, that happens naturally. The example output in your code produces something very different from the output in my code.

Comment: @steve the demo I made based in your code works fine. The problem of the _extra space_ is actualy coming from the calcul of your image size. Because if you see it well, you are setting your total image width and you compare it with wrapper width. But you dont take the image container `padding`  in the calcul. so if you cehck the tool inspection, you can see that all your row are much larger... Have a look to my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Maxigui/pen/GRqZNaV) that I made based on your code. It is more optimize.